# changing contents of a grid in wpf dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I am trying to change the contents of a grid dynamically using usercontrol.My mainWindow.xaml looks like this.

```
<Window x:Class="testapp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="524" Width="856">
<Grid Background="Black">
    <!--<Image Height="44" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="284,0,0,0" Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="229" Source="/testapp;component/Images/Picture1.png" />-->
    <Grid Height="431" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,55,0,0" Name="grid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="266" Background="Black" Opacity="0.4">
        <ListView  Height="430" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3,1,0,0" x:Name="listView1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="260" Background="Black">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height="70">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="Name : " Foreground="Yellow" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="Yellow" />
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="100">
                            <TextBlock Text="Source :" Foreground="Yellow"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source}" Foreground="Yellow"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <Button Content="create new Group" Height="36" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,392,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="254" Click="button1_Click" />
        <ContentControl x:Name="devlist"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

On clicking button1 one I am trying to change the content of the Grid named Grid1. I created a UserControl with simple textblock .

```
<UserControl x:Class="testapp.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 

         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock  Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,122,0,0" Name="textBlock1" Text="hello" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
</StackPanel>
```

My mainwindow.cs looks like this

```
namespace testapp
{

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
         Items = new List<MyItems>();
        Items.Add(new MyItems() { Name = "House Party", Source = " DLNA" });
        Items.Add(new MyItems() { Name = "Outdoor Party", Source = " DLNA" });
        listView1.ItemsSource = Items;

    }
    public List<MyItems> Items { get; set; }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        this.devlist.Content = new UserControl1();

    }

}

public class MyItems
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Source { get; set; }

}
}
```

on clicking button the content is not changing can anyone help please! Thanks in advance.

Comment: as per your question you want to change the content of Grid1 but from code you are setting the content of devlist that is ContentControl can you please tell us what you really wants to do?

Comment: I want to change the content of the grid1 on clicking button1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to first clear the grid children and then add the user control within your grid.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
// first remove the existing content within grid
grid1.Children.Clear();
// then add your user contrl here
testapp.UserControl1 usercontrol = new testapp.UserControl1();
grd1.Children.Add(usercontrol);


    }
```