# Changing the ContentControl.Content stacks the content on top of each other

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, contentcontrol

I have a MainWindow with a couple of radio buttons, a ContentControl and a button to change the content of ContentControl.

I also have a UserControl1 with a label on it. When I click the button on MainWindow to change the ContentControl.Content to UserControl1, it shows the label on top of the radio buttons I have from MainWindow. How can I change this so it acts like a page and does not stack each control on top of each other?

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Test" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Width="968" Height="560" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="540" Margin="0,10,-6,-19" Width="968">
        <StackPanel Height="74" Margin="731,446,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="229" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Button Content="Back" MinWidth="100" Margin="10,20,0,0"/>
            <Button Content="Next" MinWidth="100" Margin="10,20,0,0" Click="NextBtnClick"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <RadioButton x:Name="RadioBtn1" Content="Radio1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="312,130,95,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="76" Width="561" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold" GroupName="1"/>
        <RadioButton x:Name="RadioBtn2" Content="Radio2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="312,232,95,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="76" Width="561" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold" GroupName="1"/>
        <ContentControl x:Name="contentControl" Grid.Row="1"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
private void NextBtnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (RadioBtn2.IsChecked == true)
    {
        this.contentControl.Content = new UserControl1();
    }
}
```

After clicking the next button, I get the controls from UserControl1 stacked on top of the radio buttons.

I'm quite new to WPF so any help would be greatly appreciated. Navigating through the docs is a nightmare because I'm not sure how to tackle this problem.

Comment: If you want to stack the controls one below other, use stackpanel instead of grid

Comment: "acts like a page"? What layout do you actually want?

Comment: @mm8 I'm not sure what layout I want. As I said, I am new to wpf. Since it has defaulted me to the Grid layout, I have used the following answer to fix my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26478742/changing-contents-of-a-grid-in-wpf-dynamically

Comment: There is no "default". You need to choose an appropriate template when you implement your markup.

Comment: When I create a new WPF project, in the XAML for MainWindow, it shows Grid.

Answer (score 0):

You can trying to use `Grid` panel without defining rows and column definitions. As per your code, you are trying define the panel layout by hardcoded Margin, Width and Height. That's why contorls are rendered on top of each other.

I've changed the Grid code to define the Row Definitions so that controls are stacked on row basis. So when you click on `Button` the `ContentContrl` is loaded to last Row so (which is defined as Height="*" via RowDefinition  to take the remaining space)

You can read about WPF Panels and Grid layout at internet. [This](https://www.wpftutorial.net/GridLayout.html) can be a good start.

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Test" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Width="968" Height="560" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10 10 10 10">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
       <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
       <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
       <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
       <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions?
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <Button Content="Back" MinWidth="100" />
        <Button Content="Next" MinWidth="100" Click="NextBtnClick"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <RadioButton Grid.Row="1" x:Name="RadioBtn1" Content="Radio1" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold" GroupName="1"/>
    <RadioButton Grid.Row="2" x:Name="RadioBtn2" Content="Radio2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold" GroupName="1"/>
    <ContentControl x:Name="contentControl" Grid.Row="3"/>
   </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Working with grids is a little annoying. I just want to be able to click the button and change all the content on the window to switch to a different UserControl. If I can't find any easier solution, I may have to work with this one. Thanks!

Comment: The posted code does the same which require having appropriate layout.